# create zapi.item.get from same host

Tags: python-3.x, zabbix, zabbix-api

I'm having trouble creating the output from Zabbix API tables. I would like to output NAME(hosts), icmpping, icmploss for example.

So I would like something like this:

| hostname | ip | ping | loss | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test.server.1 | 1.1.1.1 | 0ms | 0% | up |
| test.server.2 | 8.8.8.8 | 1ms | 33% | up |

For now I have this:
From:

Code example

[image: 1]

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

The `item.get` api returns the item's definition (item id, type, key name, interval etc), not the values.

You need to call `item.get` to get the item id you need, then use the id for a `history.get` call

Try this script I wrote a while ago:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Get history values for specific items in a time range:

# ./getItemHistoryByName.py -H some-host  -I "ICMP response time" -f "26/6/2018 16:00" -t "27/6/2018 23:59"
ItemID: 77013 - Item: ICMP response time - Key: icmppingsec
1530021641 26/06/2018 16:00:41 Value: 0.1042
1530021701 26/06/2018 16:01:41 Value: 0.0993
1530021762 26/06/2018 16:02:42 Value: 0.1024
1530021822 26/06/2018 16:03:42 Value: 0.0966
[cut]
"""

from zabbix.api import ZabbixAPI
import sys, argparse
import time
import datetime


zabbixServer    = 'http://yourserver/zabbix/'
zabbixUser      = 'someuser'
zabbixPass      = 'somepass'


def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-H', required=True, metavar='Hostname')
    parser.add_argument('-I', required=True, metavar='Item Name')
    parser.add_argument('-f', required=True, metavar='From Timestamp')
    parser.add_argument('-t', required=True, metavar='Till Timestamp')

    args = parser.parse_args()


    zapi = ZabbixAPI(url=zabbixServer, user=zabbixUser, password=zabbixPass)

    fromTimestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(args.f, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").timetuple())
    tillTimestamp = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(args.t, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").timetuple())


    f  = {  'name' : args.I  }
    items = zapi.item.get(filter=f, host=args.H, output='extend' )

    for item in items:
        print "ItemID: {} - Item: {} - Key: {}".format(item['itemid'], item['name'], item['key_'])

        values = zapi.history.get(itemids=item['itemid'], time_from=fromTimestamp, time_till=tillTimestamp, history=item['value_type'])

        for historyValue in values:
            currentDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(historyValue['clock'])).strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

            print "{} {} Value: {}".format(historyValue['clock'], currentDate, historyValue['value'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: didnt manage it to work

`❯ python3 item.get4.py -H "zabbix-agent"  -I "Zabbix agent ping" -f "26/6/2022 16:00" -t "27/6/2022 23:59"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samukas/Projetos/api-zabbix/item.get4.py", line 68, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/samukas/Projetos/api-zabbix/item.get4.py", line 50, in main
    items = zapi.item.get(filter=f, host=args.H, output='extend')
TypeError: ZabbixAPISubClass.__getattr__.<locals>.method() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filter'`